# Internet not working on computer I ssh into

Tags: macos, ssh, router

So my Mac is sitting across the ocean, on my home network, with its ssh port forwarded.

I can ssh into it, and even connect to the Minecraft server running there.

However, commands like `ping` and `curl` all tell me that they can't resolve anything.

```
$ ssh myip
Password:
Last login: Wed Jul 11 15:40:42 2012 from over here
$ ping google.com
ping: cannot resolve google.com: Unknown host
```

How is this even possible? I rebooted some stuff, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Do you know if it has ever worked before? Can you connect to other hosts by IP?

Comment: Here's a test (that I developed in desperation): run that ssh session with X forwarding, and then try to run Xclock. Tell us what happens

Answer (score 3):

Are there DNS Server entries on the remote host? Seems like you're not able to do name resolution. Try to ping 209.85.148.113 (one of the hosts at google.com) for example.

Also maybe there's a firewall blocking unspecified traffic?

Comment: My favourite ip address to ping is `8.8.8.8` (Google Public DNS primary server).

Answer (score 0):

You could also check /tmp/system.cfg and set the primary dns server to google 8.8.8.8 for external lookups.

Save and this should remain persistent on reboot

Comment: There is no such file on a Mac.

Comment: Why are you giving Windows commands to a Mac user?